# Resolving package dependencies in a catkin ws

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, packages, dependencies, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the [imu_tools](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools) package on my barebones ROS installation (Debian OS) with a catkin workspace. . Following the steps listed on their github page I run `rosdep install imu_tools`. To no surprise it tells me that there are some dependencies to be resolved:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rviz_imu_plugin: Missing resource rviz
ROS path [0]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share
ROS path [2]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks
ROS path [3]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/src
imu_filter_madgwick: Missing resource actionlib
ROS path [0]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share
ROS path [2]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/stacks
ROS path [3]=/root/ros_catkin_ws/src
```

I use `rosinstall_generator --from-path ~ros_catkin_ws/src/imu_tools > imu_tools.rosinstall && rosinstall -c ~ros_catkin_ws/src imu_tools.rosinstall` to find and install all the dependencies of the package.

However when I eventually build/install with `catkin_make_isolated --install` I get that certain packages cannot be resolved. I've hunted around the wiki pages, but I can never get this step done right.

**Is there somewhere I went wrong? Is there a better way to resolve specific package dependencies?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194763/resolving-package-dependencies-in-a-catkin-ws/) by [alainh](https://answers.ros.org/users/20406/alainh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-11-16**:
I am also interested in how to solve this. Anyone have answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`imu_tools` is not released (http://wiki.ros.org/imu_tools and https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/distribution.yaml#L2671-2675) and `rosinstall_generator` can only operate on packages which are released because it uses the package index cache to get the `package.xml`'s for pacakges in order to determine their dependencies, which is created for released packages only.

The `--from-path` option is a bit naive and basically just looks at what packages are in the folder and expands to their names, for example:

```
# Given
% tree src -L 2
src
└── imu_tools
    ├── README.md
    ├── imu_filter_madgwick
    ├── imu_tools
    └── rviz_imu_plugin
% vcs st
=== ./src/imu_tools (git) ===
On branch hydro
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/hydro'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean
# This command:
% rosinstall_generator --from-path src
# Is equivalent to this command:
% rosinstall_generator imu_filter_madgwick imu_tools rviz_imu_plugin
```

So, for me `rosinstall_generator` gives up:

```
% rosinstall_generator --from-path src --rosdistro hydro --deps --deps-only --tar
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: imu_filter_madgwick, imu_tools, rviz_imu_plugin
No packages/stacks left after ignoring not released
```

Which is naive on the part of `rosinstall_generator` because it basically only needs to the `package.xml` for each package in the dependency tree. It gives up on these packages because they are not released and therefore it cannot download their `package.xml`'s from the cache, but it isn't smart enough to know that it can instead get them locally.

You can work around this by using the `catkin_pkg` Python library to get the dependencies out of the packages using something like this:

```
% python -c "from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages; print(' '.join(list(set([d.name for pkg in find_packages('src').values() for d in (pkg.build_depends + pkg.buildtool_depends + pkg.run_depends)]))))"
```

All together something like this worked for me:

```
% rosinstall_generator --rosdistro hydro --deps --tar `python -c "from catkin_pkg.packages import find_packages; print(' '.join(list(set([d.name for pkg in find_packages('src').values() for d in (pkg.build_depends + pkg.buildtool_depends + pkg.run_depends)]))))"` > imu_tools_deps.rosinstall
The following not released packages/stacks will be ignored: imu_filter_madgwick, rviz_imu_plugin
% rosinstall -c src imu_tools_deps.rosinstall
....
```

While this work around does work, I admit that `rosinstall_generator` should probably handle this for you.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0